# Struggling to return records in array properly

Tags: javascript

```
function score(string,pattern)
{
    var lowercasestring = string.toLowerCase();
    var lowercasepattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
    var patterncount = 0;
    for(i=0;i<lowercasestring.length;i++) //For loop that cycles through each character in the string
        if(i==lowercasestring.indexOf(lowercasepattern,i)) //If the pattern exists in the string past the current character it's on, add one to the patern count
            patterncount++;
    return(patterncount);
}

var web = [ {url : "www.lboro.ac.uk",  content : "Loughborough University offers degree programmes and world class research." } , {url : "www.xyz.ac.uk",  content : "An alternative University" } , {url : "www",  content : "Yet another University" } ]

function urlScores(web,pattern)
{
    var array = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=web.length-1;i++)
    {
      var record = {};
      record.url = web[i].url;
      record.score = score(web[i].content,pattern);
      if (record.score!=0)
      {
      array[i] = record;
      }
    }
    return(array);
}

alert(urlScores(web,"University"));
```

As it currently stands, the alert at the bottom only returns [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

alerting record.score and record.url gives the correct values, but alerting record on it's own just alerts [object Object]. therefore array[i] is being set as record, and that's what being returned. I'm not sure how to have record actually be displayed as {url: web[i].url value score: score(web[i].content,pattern value} (I have tried putting that in without the value part and it does the same), could anyone help?

I know console.log should display the value, but it still displays Object as well if I replace any alerts with console.log, it's something to do with how .url and .score are being put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the code is working perfectly; if you replace `alert(urlScores(web,"University"));` with `console.table(urlScores(web,"University"));` the console will show you the desired result.

Comment: I'm meant to alert the value, so I just made an arraytoreturn variable and then printed the url and score in each array value in string form, I will remember this in future though for when I learn about console.table

Answer (score 0):

Alert is just for display simple strings, try using the console and you will see it's worked..

```js
function score(string,pattern)
{
    var lowercasestring = string.toLowerCase();
    var lowercasepattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
    var patterncount = 0;
    for(i=0;i<lowercasestring.length;i++) //For loop that cycles through each character in the string
        if(i==lowercasestring.indexOf(lowercasepattern,i)) //If the pattern exists in the string past the current character it's on, add one to the patern count
            patterncount++;
    return(patterncount);
}

var web = [ {url : "www.lboro.ac.uk",  content : "Loughborough University offers degree programmes and world class research." } , {url : "www.xyz.ac.uk",  content : "An alternative University" } , {url : "www",  content : "Yet another University" } ]

function urlScores(web,pattern)
{
    var array = [];
    for(var i=0;i<=web.length-1;i++)
    {
      var record = {};
      record.url = web[i].url;
      record.score = score(web[i].content,pattern);
      if (record.score!=0)
      {
      array[i] = record;
      }
    }
    return(array);
}

console.log(urlScores(web,"University"));
```